# Question about file handling

Tags: file, file-io

Hey, I wanted to know if anyone can tell me what the difference between "file.file" and "./file.file" is. It seems to make quite a significant difference in my programs to call

`OpenFile("./file.file");`

EDIT: My mistake, I thought my question was a generic one. This is in C++ using standard library functions.

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: C++. My mistake, I thought that my question was generic.

Comment: More useful would probably be stating that you're working with WinAPI functions (or at least I'm guessing that's what you're doing).

Comment: Not in a thousand years would I use the WinAPI for personal projects my friend. Job, sure! Classes, maybe. Personal, oh HELLZ no.

Comment: Not sure what "standard library" you're using then - the C++ standard library doesn't have an OpenFile function. Are you thinking of some other less generic "standard library"?

Comment: No, I'm thinking about a completely theoretical function that does nothing but open a file. The function is not even significant. All I wanted to know was if there is a difference between "file.file" or "./file.file".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `"./File"` will be relative to the directory that your program's context is currently executing in.

Just `"File"` will be relative to the directory that the program executable resides in.

This is pretty dependent on what tool or language you're using, however.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up for me. Always good to know the reasons why something works than just roll with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the WinAPI function, see the remarks section on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365430%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Remarks
>
> **If the lpFileName parameter specifies
>   a file name and extension only**, this
>   function searches for a matching file
>   in the following directories and the
>   order shown:
>
> 1. The directory where an application is loaded.
> 2. The current directory.
> 3. The Windows system directory.
> 4. The 16-bit Windows system directory.
> 5. The Windows directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

The `./file.ext` means that it *must* be in the current directory, whereas not specifying a directory means it can be in any of the places normally checked.